# Is 'perform' a keyword in this context?

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I'm writing a simple jQuery plugin, in which I'd like to bind events to the invoking element(s).

I have something like this:

```
$=jQuery

jQuery.fn.pluginFunction = -> @each (i, element) -> new PluginObj(element)

class PluginObj
  constructor: (element) ->
    @element = $(element)
    @element.on 'change', @perform
    @element.on 'keyup', @manage_timeout

  perform: (event) =>
    console.log "foo"

  manage_timeout: (event) =>
    setTimeout(console.log("bar"), 1000)
```

I am binding this to a text input field with `$('input#target_input').pluginFunction()`. When I do, the binding for the `change` event is registered, but the binding for `keyup` doesn't do anything. If I change the name of `perform`, it stops working.

So, is `perform` a reserved word in this context? If so, is it possible to bind `keyup` to a *different* action? How should I approach that?

Comment: What kind of input are you working with? just a basic text input?

Comment: `perform` is [not a reserved word](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words). So whatever is going on is not because of that. If it works with the method being named `perform` it should work with the method being named anything valid.

Comment: Your code works as-is. http://jsfiddle.net/dYLaV/

Comment: THanks @KevinB - I guess I was looking down the wrong path, my issue must be elsewhere in my code.

Comment: `setTimeout(console.log("bar"), 1000)` is incorrect.  It should be `setTimeout(function(){ console.log("bar"); }, 1000)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the error was caused by another error in my code (which is not present in the simplified sample code posted in my question).

To explicitly answer the question I posted: `perform` is **not** a keyword, and member functions can be named whatever you'd like to name them in a class (as long as they follow normal naming  rules, of course).